# Nginx Welcome test page instead of homepage

Tags: apache, nginx, centos7, virtualmin, nginx-reverse-proxy

Server configuration :
Centos 7 + PHP7 + PHP-FPM + MariaDB 10 +Nginx as reverse proxy for Apache + Virtualmin

I'm new to setting up a server. I'm not sure where did I mess up and I have tried searching online and editing according to suggestion on Digital Ocean and many other forum but still no success. I always restart nginx, httpd and php-fpm after changes have been made.

I have 2 virtual servers, all of them open Nginx test page instead of their respective homepage.

I have been trying to configure but with no success. Please help.

Below are the configuration files for my virtual servers.

1) etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

```
server {
    listen   80; 

    root /home/~;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name localhost; 

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
     #fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;

     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

2) etc/nginx/conf.d/php-fpm.conf

```
# PHP-FPM FastCGI server
# network or unix domain socket configuration

upstream php-fpm {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;

}
```

3) etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto; 

worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;

# only log critical errors
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log crit;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
worker_connections 1024;
use epoll;
multi_accept on;
}

http {
include    mime.types;
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format main      '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
  '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '"$gzip_ratio"';

log_format download  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
  '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
  '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '"$http_range" "$sent_http_content_range"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

# cache informations about FDs, frequently accessed files
# can boost performance, but you need to test those values
open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s; 
open_file_cache_valid 2m; 
open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
open_file_cache_errors on;

# to boost I/O on HDD we can disable access logs
access_log off;
# copies data between one FD and other from within the kernel
# faster then read() + write()
sendfile on;    
# send headers in one peace, its better then sending them one by one 
tcp_nopush on;
# don't buffer data sent, good for small data bursts in real time
tcp_nodelay on;

    types_hash_max_size 2048;
index   index.php index.html index.htm;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
index   index.php index.html index.htm;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
##
# Gzip Settings
##
# reduce the data that needs to be sent over network -- for testing environment
gzip on;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 10240;
gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json  application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

# allow the server to close connection on non responding client, this will free up memory
reset_timedout_connection on;
# request timed out -- default 60
client_body_timeout 3m;
# if client stop responding, free up memory -- default 60
send_timeout 3m;
# server will close connection after this time -- default 75
keepalive_timeout   65;
# number of requests client can make over keep-alive -- for testing environment
keepalive_requests 100000;

ignore_invalid_headers on;
client_max_body_size    100m;
connection_pool_size  256;
request_pool_size  4k;
output_buffers   4 32k;
postpone_output  1460;

# limit the number of connections per single IP
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=conn_limit_per_ip:10m;
# limit the number of requests for a given session
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=req_limit_per_ip:10m rate=5r/s;
# if the request body size is more than the buffer size, then the entire (or partial)
# request body is written into a temporary file
client_body_buffer_size  128k;
# headerbuffer size for the request header from client -- for testing environment
client_header_buffer_size 3m;
# maximum number and size of buffers for large headers to read from client request
large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
# how long to wait for the client to send a request header -- for testing environment
client_header_timeout 3m;
  server_tokens off;

#nginx compression
log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] ' '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent ' '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

# Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
upstream php {
            #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
    #server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
server {
    listen 80;
#    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    #root         /home/~;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
    # zone which we want to limit by upper values, we want limit whole server
    limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
    limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;

    location ~* .(woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires max;
    }
    gzip on;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  compression;
}

#1st virtual server

 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website1.co www.website1.co;
    root /home/website1/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/website1_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/website1_error_log;

    # nginx configuration

    location / {
    #for web application
     if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(/)?api/.*$ /api/index.php;
     }
     if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(/)?customer/.*$ /customer/index.php;
     }
     if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(/)?backend/.*$ /backend/index.php;
     }
     if (!-e $request_filename){
     rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php;
     }
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;
     #web application end

    # [pre-existing configurations, if applicable]
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;

     client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_send_timeout   90;
    proxy_read_timeout   90;
    proxy_buffer_size    128k;
    proxy_buffers     4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }

 #error_page  404              /404.html;
 # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
 #
 error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

 # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 #
 location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
     fastcgi_index  index.php;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
     fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
     fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name; 

     fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
     fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
     include fastcgi_params;
 }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 location ~ /\.ht {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
     deny  all;
 }
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/website1/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/website1/ssl.key;
}

#2nd virtual server

server {
    server_name website2.co www.website2.co;
    listen 80;
    root /home/website2/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/website2_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/website2_error_log;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/website2/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/website2/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                    include fastcgi.conf;

    }

    location / {
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_send_timeout   90;
    proxy_read_timeout   90;
    proxy_buffer_size    128k;
    proxy_buffers     4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;

     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;

     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /home/website2/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/website2/ssl.key;
}
```

Any help would be very helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you place your 1st and 2nd virtual conf file? what name and location?

Comment: both in the same etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. inside http { } , just after the server { } that have server_name _;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below section from your nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

#    listen       [::]:80 default_server;

server_name _;
#root         /home/~;
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
}
# zone which we want to limit by upper values, we want limit whole server
limit_conn conn_limit_per_ip 10;
limit_req zone=req_limit_per_ip burst=10 nodelay;

location ~* .(woff|eot|ttf|svg|mp4|webm|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
expires max;
}
gzip on;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  compression;
```

}

The `server_name _;` means any virtual host and hence it is the first thing to respond in your config. Rest of the virtual hosts are not consulted only

**Edit - Aug 17**

You have lot of mess in your configs, including includes from different directory. I would suggest you remove nginx and reinstall and modify the base config again. Also you are using `httpd` also in your setup.

The `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;` means that anything that is not php is getting proxied to your httpd server and your actually root is not being used only.

Your `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` should not be inside the `location ~ \.php$ {` block, rather it should be inside the `location \ {` block. Also there should be no `proxy_pass` in your `location \ {` block

Comment: removed it but both website still showing the "Welcome to nginx on Fedora!" Test Page. I have added a info.php file, I can access it at website1.co/info.php without problem.

Comment: tried it, still showing the "Welcome to nginx on Fedora!" Test Page.
I have tried on a new browser and deleted caches, still same problem.

Comment: Remove this also `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` And only have the two virtual server sections and no other server

Comment: Hi, I have remove it but problem still there. Is it a problem with virtualmin configuration? It's pretty much on default configuration.

Comment: I hope you Are restarting nginx after the changes?

Comment: yes, I always restart nginx, httpd and php-fpm. should I restart my vps? shouldn't have any changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152112/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-dswong).